# How to re-center polymer paper dialog after dynamic content loads..?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer how to re-center paper dialog after dynamic image loads..??

Please check image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Is the best way I found yet..**

If the content changes the dialog needs to be notified:

**this.$.dialog.notifyResize();**

```js
this.$.dialog.toggle();
if(this.$.dialog.opened) {
  this.async(function () {
    this.$.dialog.notifyResize();
  });
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/68